# how to use tensorflow saved_model.load

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

I am following [this official tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/text_classification_with_tf_hub) to build a text classification model

I am exporting the trained model as such

```
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec([embedded_text_feature_column]))
export_path = estimator.export_saved_model("./models/sentiment", serving_input_fn)
```

I was not sure how to pass a sample sentence (e.g. "it was a great movie") to do prediction when loading.

```
imported = tf.saved_model.load(b'./models/sentiment/1586848142')
infer = imported.signatures["serving_default"]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need to load the model

```
imported = tf.saved_model.load(export_path)


def predict(x):
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.features.feature["sentence"].bytes_list.value.extend([x])
    out = imported.signatures["predict"](examples=tf.constant([example.SerializeToString()]))['probabilities']
    return out

x = b"I am happy"
predict(x)
```

Comment: sigiture only has `signatures["serving_default"]`. Do you know what we need to do in this case?