# how to use tensorflow saved_model.load to do prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, prediction, sentiment-analysis

I need to do prediction using a saved model in TensorFlow.
Here I export the model:

```
def serving_input_fn_builder(max_seq_length):
    def _serving_input_fn():
        feature_spec = {
            "input_ids": tf.placeholder(tf.int32,
                                        shape=[None, max_seq_length]),
            "input_mask": tf.placeholder(tf.int32,
                                         shape=[None, max_seq_length]),
            "segment_ids": tf.placeholder(tf.int32,
                                          shape=[None, max_seq_length])
        }
        return tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(
            feature_spec)()
    return _serving_input_fn

def export_tf_model(estimator, serving_input_fn, export_name="export"):
    estimator.export_savedmodel(
        export_dir_base=f"{export_name}",
        serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_fn)
```

```
serving_input_fn = serving_input_fn_builder(FLAGS.max_seq_length)
        export_model_params = {
            "export_name": "export"
        }
        export_tf_model(estimator, serving_input_fn, **export_model_params)
```

Lets say I have saved model `saved_model.pb`. Now I need to load it and do predictions.

```
checkpoint_path = "./Saved_Model_tf/saved_model.pb"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

new_model = tf.saved_model.load(checkpoint_dir)
infer = new_model.signatures["serving_default"]
print(infer) ##this is the result of print: {'prob': <tf.Tensor 'Softmax:0' shape=(None, 3) dtype=float32>, 'logits': <tf.Tensor 'loss/BiasAdd:0' shape=(None, 3) dtype=float32>, 'intent': <tf.Tensor 'ArgMax:0' shape=(None,) dtype=int32> => here the intent is the prediction

def predict(x):
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.features.feature["sentence"].bytes_list.value.extend([x])
    out = new_model.signatures["predict"](examples=tf.constant([example.SerializeToString()]))['probabilities']
    return out

x = "The movie is awesome"
predict(x)
```

It raises this error:

`return self._signatures[key] KeyError: 'predict'`

I reviewed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61206650/how-to-use-tensorflow-saved-model-load) and this [link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/guide/saved_model.ipynb?hl=es-419#scrollTo=K5srGzowfWff) but was not successful to get it work.